# Inserting Related MySQL Data with AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql

I'm looking at a database that has 3 tables into which I have to insert data:

```
resource
  id (AUTO_INCREMENT)
  name

resource_item
  id (AUTO_INCREMENT)
  name
  resource_id (FK ref resource.id)

resource_item_business_function
  id (AUTO_INCREMENT)
  business_function_name
  resource_item_id
```

What I'm struggling with is the fact that this must be scripted. I'm only inserting 1 `resource` record so I can script the insert into the `resource` table easily enough. I have ~20 `resource_item` records to insert for that `resource` and I can even do that easily enough using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. The question is...*how do I insert into `resource_item_business_function`?*

I have no idea how to insert the *proper* `resource_item_id` into each `resource_item_business_function` record. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use LAST_INSERT_ID() after each insert into resource_item. So your final script could look something like this:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
SET @RESOURCE_ID=0;

INSERT INTO resource ( NULL, "Some Name");
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @RESOURCE_ID;

INSERT INTO resource_item ( NULL, "Some Name", RESOURCE_ID );
INSERT INTO resource_item_business_function ( NULL, "Some Name", LAST_INSERT_ID() );
...etc...
INSERT INTO resource_item ( NULL, "Some Name", RESOURCE_ID );
INSERT INTO resource_item_business_function ( NULL, "Some Name", LAST_INSERT_ID() );

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Ugh. I was hoping there was some kind of clever scripting/looping I could do to avoid individual SQL statements. The other side of this is that there is no cascading of FKs, so I was hoping I could write the script to automagically delete existing records if executed multiple times. For clarity, I left that last part out. :-)

Comment: And then drop the procedures once the script completes its execution, I guess? I definitely don't want this kind of procedure to linger on the db.

Comment: If it is not an ongoing operation, I would not use database side SP's or triggers.

Comment: Yeah. This is, in theory, a one-time operation. The multiple executions represent the trial and error of the testing process.

Comment: Reading back on your first response. You will get errors generated by using the inserts above. Just replace `COMMIT;` with `ROLLBACK;` This will test your inserts within the transactiona nd revert before completion. All integrity checks are done within the transaction, so this should not affect your testing.